# Hover transform not removed when mouse leaves svg element, Safari only

Tags: svg, safari, hover, transform

I have a minimal piece of code that should result in a rectangle being transformed when hovering over it. It works fine on Chrome and Edge but Safari leaves the rectangle in its transformed state when the mouse has left it.

```html
 <html>
        <head>  
            <style>
                #rect:hover{
                    transform: scale(0.9);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id="divRect">
                <svg width="400" height="110">
                <rect id="rect" width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can report [webkit bugs here](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the steer to Bugzilla Robert. Looks like a problem of this nature was reported a few years ago and further insight from the contributor led me to a workaround. If I add a transform to scale(1) in the CSS before the hover it works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Can workaround by adding initial transform like this-

```
<style>
    #rect{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    #rect:hover{
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
</style>
```